# How to customize the colors of Qt applications in Ubuntu (16.10)?

Tags: theme, qt

After quite a lot of searching, I see nowhere how to change the colors of my Qt applications.

I already created a custom dark gtk theme in `~/.themes/` by modifying the default Ambiance, but now I need to also change Qt apps. And funnily, they already display in dark (sometimes too dark) so I may have changed it a long time ago (no idea how).

For example I use **Scribus** and **Mendeleydesktop** that use Qt (Qt5 and Qt4 respectively).

I tried:

1. to create a css style sheet with `background: blue; color: green;` as a test, but executing:

   ```
   mendeleydesktop -stylesheet myqtstyle.css
   ```

   does not affect anything (just complains: `Could not parse application stylesheet`)
2. `qt4-config`, no effect.
3. I searched in `gconf-editor` and `dconf-editor` if there are settings for Qt, no luck.
4. I modified the gtk-3.20, gtk-3.0 and gtk-2 files of my theme, no effect.

Does someone have a simple solution for customizing my Qt apps?